# Wrap contents of span

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this span: `<span style="font-weight:bold;">bold. </span>` and a reference to it(the element) called span.

I want to wrap everything inside of my span element in some new tags, example `<p>` tags: `<span style="font-weight:bold;"><p>bold. </p></span>`

I know I can call `span.wrap("<p></p>")` but this wraps the span and not the spans contents. When I try to do `span.append("<p>")` the new tags are just created at the beginning of the contents and the same happens with appendElement.

What is the best way to wrap the contents of a span/element and not the whole element?

Update: Elements also has wrap but calling span.getAllElements() and then wrap on that provides the same result as span.wrap() and span.children() is 0 for this example.

Update 2: As a work around I was able to get the content with span.html(), store that as a temporary String, add the desired tags around that content and then set the spans content to that via the span.html(newContent); If there is not a better way I will just answer my own question.

Comment: What does this have to do with Android?

Comment: Removed the tag, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to wrap text node use

```
span.childNode(0).wrap("<p>");
```

Edit:
an example with various use cases:

```
String html = "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">bold.</span><span></span><span><a>text</a></span>";
Document parsedDoc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements selects = parsedDoc.select("span");

for (Element span : selects) {
    List<Node> childNodes = span.childNodes();
    if (childNodes.size() > 0 && span.childNode(0).childNodes().size() == 0) {
        span.childNode(0).wrap("<p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this seems to be working for my current example but I need to do some more testing to see what happens if the span has more then one element.